# Scala BigDecimal division

Tags: scala, bigdecimal

What use is the division operator on a scala `BigDecimal`?

```
val d1 = BigDecimal(2)
val d2 = BigDecimal(3)
val div = d1 / d2 //throws ArithmeticException: non-terminating decimal expansion
```

In order to get this to work, you need to define a `DECIMAL128` context on the decimals. Unfortunately the only way I can see of doing this is:

```
val div = new BigDecimal(d1.bigDecimal.divide(d2.bigDecimal, MathContext.DECIMAL128)) //OK!
```

But this is just a mess! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug in Scala -> see [Ticket #1812](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1812). Apparently, it is fixed in Scala 2.8. You can also download a fix from the bug report which implements a `BigDecimal` with a `MathContext` attached to it. Using the given [`Decimal.scala`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/attachment/ticket/1812/Decimal.scala), I can write something like this and get it to run without error:

```
val d1 = Decimal128(1)
val d2 = Decimal128(3)
val d3 = d1 / d2 // works, gives a truncated result
```

Therefore, you could either compile the given `Decimal.scala` file and add it to your `classpath` or wait for Scala 2.8, which will already have it in the standard library.

**EDIT** See [revision 18021](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/18021) of the Scala standard library for the changes to `BigDecimal` implementing this.

Hope it helps :)

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`